# Dynamic reference in excel from cell

Tags: excel, dynamic, reference

I would like to get reference for row from another cell but fix column.
For example:

This is normal way. In cell `A1` will be `YES`

```
| -  | A  | B |
| -- | -- |-- |
| 1  | =B1|YES|
| 2  |  1 |NO |
```

I'd like to chage number 1 in `=B1` to be read from cell `A2`. something like

| - | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | =B(A2) | YES |
| 2 | 1 | NO |

Why? Because then i will change number in cell `A2` from `1` to `2` then will change cell `A1` from `YES` to `NO`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INDEX` formula to get the desired results like below in cell B2.

`=INDEX(C:C,A2)`

Comment: This is not what i'm looking form. I understand `INDEX` is when reference is on one sheet, applicable for row and column. I'm looking for something which can by used more freely. For example: Reference column is been read from another sheet as row reference.

Comment: @DávidKuruc it is incorrect interpretation. You can use INDEX with references on different sheet.